# Testing Paypal sandbox

Tags: python, django, paypal, checkout

I want to integrate `Paypal checkout` button in my store. I am testing it using sandbox credentials from `paypal`. The problem is, a transaction from Indian user to another Indian user is not possible. Both my sandbox accounts(buyer and seller) has its country set to India. So I am unable to test it. I intend to use it for accepting payments internationally anyway. So, is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Make non-Indian test accounts.

Comment: @geewiz That's exactly what I want to do. The question is, how to do it?